Adaptive Correlation Threshold for QPSK
A single-carrier QPSK signal passed through a fading channel is correlated in the receiver using standard complex-conj correlation with a known sequence.  The received signal's amplitude fluctuates due to fading, and therefore the correlation threshold must be able to adapt to the signal's received amplitude and thermal noise level.
Can someone provide a robust algorithm (or reference) for an adaptive threshold in this situation?  The rms value of the received signal is measurable, and we are dealing with a slow-fading channel such that the coherence time is greater than the duration of the preamble.  Thank you.

As you say, you need to adjust the threshold according to your desired performance metric. Possibly a constant false alarm ratio (CFAR)? You don't tell us how you'd do that for a constant channel, but we simply assume you have a function that given an SNR estimate and total observed power – or equivalently, an SNR estimate and signal power estimate, or SNR and noise power, but the total observed power is the easiest metric to get.
So, you need to estimate SNR of a PSK modulation in a slow fading channel.
The classical estimator here is certainly the Kurtosis-based estimator. You'll find a rundown of that and a comparison with others in D. R. Pauluzzi and N. C. Beaulieu, "A comparison of SNR estimation techniques for the AWGN channel," IEEE Trans. Communications, Vol. 48, No. 10, pp. 1681-1691, 2000, online, as "D Second- and Fourth-Order Moments ($M_2, M_4$) Estimator".
I think of special interest to you might be the "E. Signal-to-Variation Ratio (SVR) Estimator" from that survey.
Anyways, you just update the SNR estimate regularly, and just observe the signal's magnitude squares as total power, and use that to update your threshold.
Of course, often you can assume low-pass behaviour on channel changes, so it might be appropriate to not follow every change in estimated SNR or total power instantly. Whether that just takes the form of a single-pole "exponentially weighted moving average" IIR or a complex prediction model based on training a large neural network with additional data extracted from decision feedback, that depends fully on what you know (and what effort your receiver can spend, realistically).
Now, my suspicion here is that in exactly the situation you're looking for the preamble, you have nothing else to work with, because you're not in an active transmission (unless the last active transmission is not long past, in which case you'd use the metrics as derived with the methods described above).
In that case, where there's no signal you can extract info from – you can't base any adaptive threshold on anything! You only know the general statistics of your channel and the general statistics of your transmitter. In that case, only one thing: you define which percentage of preambles you're OK with missing, and then calculate the threshold such that given your assumed channel statistics and the observed total power, you get the missed detection rate you want – but nothing here is really adaptive. You just correlate, and compare the correlation coefficient with the total power in one correlation length, and when that ratio is above a fixed threshold, you signal a detection.

You can plot the CDF curves of correlation output peak with and without signal to decide where to put threshold. You can put threshold such that Probability of Mis-Detection meets, say, <=1% for a Probability of False Alarm=1% criteria. You can collect the data over 1000s of channel realizations so that it averages out fading channel effect.
A rough illustration is given below. The blue CDF curve is of correlation output values with no signal, and the red is of signal. The orange line is the threshold such that it meets 1% False Alarm (blue curve=99%) but for red curve value is <=1%.

